# Need to access InstaOn.com from Ubuntu

Tags: browser, plugins

I need to access my DVR over Internet using Firefox on Ubuntu. The web site is www.instaon.com, but when I try to login it asks for ActiveX plug-in. Is there a alternate for ActiveX for Ubuntu or any other way to make it work?

Thanks,
Ataullah

Comment: http://pipelight.net/cms/plugin-npactivex.html is the only thing I know that could do this. But google canned that so you will also need an old chrome (...)

Comment: The title "ActiveX for Ubuntu" really confused me, I reverted this edit to your question to make it less irritating and to get more constructive answers. As people noted, ActiveX, Flash or Java browser plug-ins are a security nightmare and have therefore been phased out. What I don't understand is how this site relates to your DVR? It doesn't look like this company is making DVRs or special services related to DVRs. If you can provide more details about what you actually do on this site we may find an alternative. It's hard to believe that an ActiveX only site is still alive or that it will be

Comment: It looks like this site just provides a DDNS service https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KGVT5A2yok probably use one of the many other DDNS providers?

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer** No.

**Long answer**:
`ActiveX` only works on Microsoft Internet Explorer. Unfortunately, there aren't any alternatives, just like there isn't and alternative to Flash. Not to mention, `ActiveX` is really old and outdated, full of security holes and vulnerabilities, and really should be killed with fire.

Comment: pipelight with  npactivex and an old chrome?

Comment: @Rinzwind - Oh, that just sounds lovely :)

Comment: not really. it uses wine ...

Comment: @Rinzwind - I think you misunderstood.  I was saying that it sounds awful. (Errr... in English, if you say something is "lovely" but say it with a certain tone, it means the opposite. It's sarcasm.)

Comment: @AndroidDev And I thought Rinzwind was being sarcastic too, better not use sarcasm.